# Babel преобразовывает не весь код в ES5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Настроен бейбел, все работает отлично, но на некоторых браузерах, не работает, так как несколько кусков код не траспайлятся, нашел один кусок код с arrow function.

Например вот два блока которые в бандле не превращены в es5,

```
function useCommittedRef(value) {
  var ref = (0, _react.useRef)(value);
  (0, _react.useLayoutEffect)(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);
  return ref;
}
```

2 код

```
function useEventCallback(fn) {
  const ref = (0, _useCommittedRef.default)(fn);
  return (0, _react.useCallback)(function (...args) {
    return ref.current(...args);
  }, [ref]);
}
```

Webpack

```
let path = require('path');
let HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
let webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    entry: './src/index.jsx',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('public'),
        filename: 'app-bundle.js',
        publicPath: process.env.CONTEXT
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx']
    },
    module: {

        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {modules: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                query: {
                    name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['babel-preset-env', 'react', ['es2015', { loose: true, modules: false }], 'stage-2', "transform-class-properties"]
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: require.resolve('style-loader'),
                    },
                    {
                        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                    },
                    {
                        loader: require.resolve('sass-loader'),
                    },

                ]
            }
        ],
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],

    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            inject: 'body',
            vendorsFilename: process.env.CONTEXT
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production'),
                CONTEXT: JSON.stringify(process.env.CONTEXT)
            }
        })
    ],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: { index: process.env.CONTEXT },
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 8081,
        contentBase: './',
    }
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["es2015"],
    "react",
    "stage-3"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

Comment: стоит добавить исходный код, и какие настройки для babel используются.

Comment: @Grundy добавил код

Comment: а что это за код? раз до него не дошел babel, значит и не нужно

Comment: а как узнать где он используется, по бандлу фиг скажешь откуда он

Comment: вообще похоже на что-то внутриреактовское. Если так, возможно какие-то неправильные импорты используются

Comment: node_modules/react-bootstrap/dist/react-bootstrap.js

Comment: Тут есть такая функция

Comment: node_modules/@restart/hooks/useEventCallback.js

Comment: Тут вторая function useEventCallback(fn) {
  const ref = (0, _useCommittedRef.default)(fn);
  return (0, _react.useCallback)(function (...args) {
    return ref.current(...args);
  }, [ref]);
}

Comment: То есть все находятся в react-bootstrap, useCommittedRef.js hook, hook useEventCallback

Comment: ты импорт как-то прописывал к файлам в которых эти функции?

Comment: Рекомендую для начала обновить Babel и перейти на `@babel/preset-env` если возможно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо добавить

```
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/promise';
import 'core-js/stage/2';
import 'core-js/fn/object/assign';
import "isomorphic-fetch"
```

Comment: куда добавить? Почему?

Comment: Некоторые вещи байбел не триспилит, надо вручную либо core-js либо polifil

Answer (score 0):

Установите и пропишите в конфиге babelrc (или babel.config.js, или в webpack.config.js)

> @babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-arrow-functions

Comment: Этот плагин и так входит в комплект пресета es2015, так что ваш ответ ничего не меняет и помочь вряд ли может

Comment: у меня стоит .babelrc ничего она для билда не помагает

Comment: в коде стоит же...

Comment: используйте другие пресеты:
@babel/preset-env, @babel/preset-react

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env вот подробное описание первого пресета